# Spring Data JPA save method does not update database entity when given id is already present

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

For some reason my JPA repository does not update existing database entity but creating a new one even if argument object has id that is already present in the database.

Here is my configuration:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.someName.repository.support"
                  transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager_Support"
                  entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory_Support"/>

<bean id="transactionManager_Support" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory_Support"/>
    <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory_Support" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceSupport"/>
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:persistence.xml"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit_SUPPORT"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit_SUPPORT" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
 <!-- List of all entity classes here -->
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />    
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I have a wrapper method in service defined like this:

```
@Transactional("transactionManager_Support")
public TestingResult save(TestingResult testingResult) {

    try {
        testingResult = testingResultRepository.saveAndFlush(testingResult);
        LOGGER.info(String.format("Testing Result with id [%d] was successfully persisted", testingResult.getId()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error persisting Testing Result");
    }

    return testingResult;
}
```

This method is called several times. The first time testingResult has null id, so it is saved with new id as expected. After that the same object with some new properties set is again saved, as i need to update existing entity in DB. But instead a new record in DB is created with id incremented by one.
Can anyone clarify why does such behavior occur?

Comment: Do you have the @Version column?

Comment: No, i don't. But i think i have found the problem. TestingResult class has another entity as a property. When i saved it for the first time, this property was null. Then i saved the same object but with child entity set and in db a new record was created. But when i tried to save it again, with same child entity, it worked fine and updated the record. So apparently relationships affects the way identity of the object are treated.

Comment: @RossiRobinsion what will happen if there is Version column?